# Office Ribbon control events in c#

Tags: c#

I'm using this third party control

http://officeribbon.codeplex.com/documentation

and i can't find the event when the tab is clicked

example picture: [image]

what i want is to fire an event(execute some code) when file tab is clicked

and fire an event(execute some code) when Tags tab is clicked.

and what event do i need? i tried the events. but it doesnt work

im using c# 2010

Comment: which third party ribbon are you using

Comment: why do i received a down vote? @PankajGupta i already stated it on my post sir

Comment: Don't know buddy who given down vote for your question.But i put my answer below down is it helpful for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

> i would suggest you can use inbuilt ribbon . these have all the functionality what we need , two type ribbons are available xml and visual designer . visual designer is easy to handle , work same like asp.net or winform control . Hope it will help if not so show your code.